# Looking for DAX formula to calculate percentage per category for a year for a multiple choice ques

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have done almost everything but not able to achieve the desired solution.

I have two surveys for 2020 and 2021 which have multiple-choice questions.

So there are two tables:

[Table 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBwZ3.png)

[Table 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fF5KY.png)

Since it's a multiple-choice question, I want to calculate the percentage of respondents who chose e.g. western Europe as an attractive region based on total number of respondents for a survey. For this, I have linked the above two charts using Survey ID.

I want a measure to calculate the last column in below table 3:

[Table 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2tLR.png)

For eg. for Western Europe, 3 respondents in 2021 survey have marked it as a attractive region. Now the percentage I want is 3 divided by 4 (respondents in 2021 survey). The percentage I am getting is 3/9 (respondents in 2020+2021 survey)

This is the DAX I am using:

Denominator = calculate(sum('Table 2'[Weightage]),allexcept('Table 2',Table 2[Survey year]))
%category = divide(sum('Table 1'[Weightage]),Denominator,0)

Please suggest the change in DAX function to require desired percentage. Since its a multiple choice question I am facing issues. I really need this to be resolved, please suggest what can be done. Thankyou.

Comment: insted of image add sample data to your post.

Comment: Where do you get the 4 for western europe, i can't see from your table also